# Cannot connect to MySql from Xamain.iOs and Xamarin.Android using C#

Tags: android, ios, mysql, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Im building mob app for ios and android using xamarin studio on Mac and i want to connect to a mysql DB . so Ive downloaded the MySql connector from the below link : http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

and referenced it in my code and added the below code :

```
    MySqlConnectionStringBuilder conn_string = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder ();
    conn_string.Server = "serverIP";
    conn_string.UserID = "user";
    conn_string.Password = "pssword";
    conn_string.Database = "DBTest";

    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(conn_string.ToString());
    conn.Open();
    conn.Close()
```

When i build the solution ,the build is successful but when I run the solution ,it will give me the following error :

```
  System.TypeLoadException has been thrown Could not load type        'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTrace' from assembly 'MySql.Data, Version=6.9.5.0,    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d'.
```

at

conn.Open();

I found later that this version is not compatible with xamarin.ios or xamarin.android profile .

After long research ,the choices available are :

-Use a MySql.Data.dll assembly built against a PCL profile that is supported by Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS
-Recompile the MySql.Data source against the Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS profile assemblies.

Does anybody have a workable DLL or was able to go through the above solutions or if there are any other ideas ?

Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

I think the general approach when connecting to remote databases from a mobile app is to call a webservice (preferably rest based service with JSON). This way your logic for connecting to a MySQL, Oracle, SQL server database is solely on the server. For connecting to local databases on the device generally most folks will use SQLite. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As of my opinion it won't be wise to connect directly to a MySQL database from an iOS app.

Personally I would need to make a web-based backend using REST, JSON or PHP. Or even a combo :)

Check this link for understanding the logic behind it: http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/#connectiphonetomysql

Otherwise try check your thread at the Xaramin forums :) [Link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/28784/error-when-using-mysql-data-dll-to-connect-to-mysql-db-in-ios-xamarin) for others

Comment: Thanks,Im aware that it is better to use a webservice to connect to mysql but i have a specific scenario where i want to connect directly to mysql in xamarin ios/android and i wanted to check if a MySql.data.dll (portable class library) version is available .

Comment: I tried what Snowwolf725 suggested on the Xamarin forums and it worked quite well for myself - Did you try it yet?